# What extra Characters (non ASCII ) can be printed in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, character, printf

Is there a reference list of non ASCII characters that can be printed using sprintf, fprintf, or disp ?

Characters such as :

```
° º ♦ ∎ ⊠ ❯ •
```

If I type disp('∆')

I get a blank reply, the character is not printed.

Comment: do you mean ascii table?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, there's ASCII tables all over the place :\ you just have to google for them. Am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Dmitry check question

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2CH660/?product=ML&solution=1-2CH660 could be relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean the output of:

```
 char(1:255)
```

Note that in [Matlab's char](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/char.html), only the first 127 characters correspond to (non-extended) ASCII, anything after that is Unicode16.  The reason Matlab does not display it correctly, is due to the fact that the Matlab command window does not treat Unicode very well by default.
In any case, the output of the characters to file should not result in any difference; it is just a *display* issue.

However, the undocumented Matlab guru, [Yair Altman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233829/yair-altman) (see [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-matlab-labels/)), shows how one can add HTML-aware labels to a plot. You can therefore put a Unicode characters into such a label using the `&#xHEXCODE;` syntax, for example:

```
figure;
labelStr=[ '<html> &deg; &diams; &#8718; &#8864; </html>'];
jLabel = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JLabel',labelStr);
[hcomponent,hcontainer] = javacomponent(jLabel,[100,100,40,20],gcf);
```

Comment: Yes !! But are these the only characters matlab can display ? Is it possible to display more characters (such as the ones available in Word or Character views for Mac ? )